# Wierd bit of PHP code 1 == 2

Tags: php

Anyone have any idea what this bit of code is trying to do?

```
if($module_key == 8 AND 1 == 2)
```

$module_key is a defined variable. It can have a value of 0 - 9. It's the rest of the line that has me scratching my head.

Comment: Seems to me like this would always return false.  No idea what the purpose would be.  Where are you getting it from?

Comment: Since when is `AND` valid php code?  Shouldn't that be `&&`?  The _actual_ code snippet might help, but I agree with the other comments, it's probably just a lazy debugging hook.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Surprisingly, `AND` *is* valid syntax. The difference with && is in the precedence when interpreted.

`$g = true && false` acts like `($g = (true && false))`. 
`$h = true and false` acts like: `(($h = true) and false)`.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @WilboBaggins - TIL.  Thanks for the reference link.  One more reason I'm glad I spend as little time as possible working with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly likely it's there to invalidate the condition on purpose, i.e. make it always evaluate to false, for debugging purposes.

Comment: I sometimes use an if(1==1) to return true on purpose, for testing reasons. Probably an easier way but it's the first thing that pops into my mind. So I concur!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes developers put in "always false" statements on if statements during web site construction / debugging to stop it from running. This can be easier than commenting it all out if there are comments in the block you want to disable:

```
if (originalCondition && 1 == 2)
{
   /*
    This comment means commenting out the
    block would require editing this out
    */

   /* code */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any point in it, perhaps the developer that wrote that is his way of preventing a block of code from running because he is debugging something.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a way of *commenting out* a part of the code without destroying the original.

I write myself sometimes `if (false) then ...` and change it to true if appropriate. Maybe you should not have this in production code...